# POP concept - storing elements in different class

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

Hi I am creating test framework based on POP.

Is it good if I keep all elements on the PageClass e.g:

```
public class DraggablePage extends BaseExtendablePage {

@FindBy(xpath = "//a[@href= '#tabs-1']") WebElement defaultFunctionalityTableHeader;
@FindBy(xpath = "//a[@href= '#tabs-3']") WebElement constraintMovementTableHeader;  
 ....
```

Or is it better if I have the specific pageClass to keep those objects and return it in methods e.g:

```
public class DraggablePageObjects {

@FindBy(id = "ui-id-1") static WebElement defaultFunctionalityTableHeader;

public static WebElement getDefaultFunctionalityTableHeader(){
    return defaultFunctionalityTableHeader;
}
```

In second example I need to invoke methods to get element like:

```
 DraggablePageObjects.getDefaultFunctionalityTableHeader();
```

Or maybe there is a better idea to keep those elements?

Comment: Do you have a POC (working) of the POP concept? How different is your `Page Class` from `Page Object`?

Comment: What is 'POP concept'?

Comment: @Debanjan I have all my elements in pageClassess, nothing else.

Comment: @Grasshopper Page Object Pattern